# Getting 504 gateway timeout, regardless of max_time, max_size settings etc

Tags: php, wordpress, dedicated-server

I've set my setting in PHP fairly high:

```
memory_limit: 256M

max_execution_time: 999

max_input_time:9999

post_max_size:128M

Upload_max_filesize: 128M
```

(Also tried adding)

```
max_input_vars=6000;

realpath_cache_size=256K;

realpath_cache_ttl=1800;

allow_url_fopen=Off;
```

I have these set in Plesk's domain level PHP settings. I've also tried with PHP **5.6.28** and **7.0.12**. PHP is run as "**FPM served by Apache**" if that's any help.

I've got an ecommerce WordPress and anytime I want to run something as simple as deleting/importing more than 60 products/posts at once I get a gateway timeout, anything that takes more than about minute seems to timeout, it's dedicated server with an 8 core processor and 16 gigs of ram. But I've had better performance on a shared hosting package with WordPress.

I'm at a loss as to what could be the cause, or even where I should be looking to figure out the problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you benchmarked your database server? Have you enabled code and data caching? Have you studied the exact point in WP code where the timeout occurs?

Comment: How do I benchmark a server? What would actually affect it's performance it, it's a brand new install and it's not as though the database is very big. A couple of megs at most. There is no caching active at the moment, but when I've used caching it seems to make it worse. No I haven't, but I'm not sure where I should be looking to see that.

Comment: I haven't seen a case where caching makes things worse. Enable that as the first step.

Comment: That was a first step it made it worse.

Comment: Caching plugins can make Wordpress less reliable. You need to work out what's taking the CPU (PHP/database/web server), run "top" or similar after you make a problematic request. Try changing web server timeout not just PHP. Check the units, ms vs sec.